# What are the most common EMACS commands?

Tags: emacs

I'd like to re-map my EMACS to put the most common commands on the home row. Which commands are the most common? Is there some way I could measure this? Has someone already attempted this?

Comment: Which are the most common commands that _you_ use?

Comment: Note that many of the most popular packages exist to *automate* common operations (line or paragraph filling, spell checking, re-indenting, ...) this will depend *a lot* on what goodies the user has installed...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say it depends on the user.  So measure your own most-frequently used:

[Link](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/command-frequency.el)

And although Randal was mostly making a joke, `self-insert-command` **is** my most frequently used, consistently around 20-25%.

If you take a look at the [web page for command-frequency](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/command-frequency.html), you'll see that the most common commands are:

- self-insertion
- movement
- isearch
- paste
- save-buffer
  ...

Answer (score 12):

The most common command is probably `self-insert-command`, but that's already bound to most keys directly. :)